# Radio button disappeared after placing inside radio group in linear layout

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I want to get two radio buttons side by side so used horizontal layout, but one issue I encountered is both the radio buttons are getting selected instead of the normal behaviour where anyone radio button should get selected. So I have used `radio group` inside a `linear layout horizontal` but surprisingly all radio buttons got disappeared.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="22dip"
        android:background="@color/silver"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

       <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="22dip"
        android:background="@color/silver" >

       <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="/share" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="/value" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        </RadioGroup>

       </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

I need to get the radio button below the `abc`.

Full XML

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="@color/dark_snuff"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="@color/silver"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="23dip"
            android:background="@color/silver"
            android:text=" Brokerage"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="22dip"
        android:background="@color/silver"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

       <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="22dip"
        android:background="@color/silver" >

       <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="/share" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="/value" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        </RadioGroup>

       </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText8"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/backgroud"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="0.0" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText9"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.00"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/backgroud"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="0.0" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `RadioGroup extends LinearLayout` so there shouldn't be any need for the LL if it only contains the RG. Also, show the rest of your xml.

Comment: @codeMagic thanks for your reply.. please find my XML code.. if I remove `Radio  Group` I can see radio buttons

Comment: What if you keep RG and remove LL?

Comment: @codeMagic If I keep only `RG` then also result is same radio button still disappears

Comment: @codeMagic Thanks for your help I have figured out the answer.. I am missing `orientation` parameter in radio group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have figured out the answer as I am missing `Orientation` parameter for `radio group`....

Added this parameter `android:orientation="horizontal"`

Now XML is

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="22dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/silver" >
```

Now there is no need for `linear layout horizontal`

Comment: I'm glad it's working but there must have been something else going on. Like it's parent. `LinearLayout`, there is no need for that attribute as it's default value is `horizontal`.

Comment: @codeMagic I am curious to know how can we know the source code or something indepth of the android... like the one you said `Radio Group extends Linear Layout` which I don't know.. can you please share with me how can I learn those concepts.. apologize if it is a premature question... Also sorry if I am troubling you.. thanks

Comment: No trouble. **[Looking in the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html)** you can see the class inheritance list underneath the class name. That is where you can see `RadioGroup extends LinearLayout`. You don't need the source for that. You should be able to find the source code in your sdk but you can also download the source **[through the docs](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html)**. It can also be found on github and mirrored other places.

Comment: @codeMagic Thanks for your response will start my learning from your suggestion...